# Derivative of Integral with Function in Bound

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

I need to evaluate the following derivative in the scope of a PDE class

$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{x_s(t)} \rho(x,t) \text dx$

For some reason I am not able to obtain the right answer using a simple chain rule with the Fundamental theorem of Calculus. Here is what I tried (where $\frac {\partial\mu}{\partial x} =\rho$). Please note the function has a jump discontinuity at $x_s(t)$.

$\begin {align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{x_s(t)} \rho(x,t) \text dx &= \frac{d}{dt} [\mu(x_s(t),t)-\mu(a,t)]\\
&= \frac{dx_s}{dt}\frac {\partial\mu}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}-(\frac{da}{dt}\frac {\partial\mu}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial t})\\
&= \frac{dx_s}{dt}\frac {\partial\mu}{\partial x}\\
&= \frac{dx_s}{dt}\rho
\end{align}$

Which is only one term of what I should get. Any hint of where I did something wrong is appreciated, this is making me feel like I forgot calculus...

EDIT: Here is what I should get

$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{x_s(t)} \rho(x,t) \text dx = \int_a^{x_s(t)} \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} \text dx + \frac{dx_s}{dt}\rho$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}$ are evaluated at different values $(x_s(t),t)$ and $(a,t)$.  Put in these values and you will get the correct answer.

Comment: I see that now that you mention it actually of course. Thanks!